# How does totalSupply() get updated if not called?

Tags: solidity, nft

Let's say we have this bit of code here

```
    function gift(address _account) external onlyOwner {

        if (totalSupply() + 1 > MAX_SUPPLY) {
            revert Contract__MintGiftExceeded();
 
        }
        _safeMint(_account, (s_nftIdCounter).current());
        (s_nftIdCounter).increment();

    }
```

I've noticed that in this function while we do not add the gifted NFT to `totalSupply()`,
we only do `counters.increment()` , and `totalSupply()` still gets to know the total number of tokens.

So I have been wondering how does that actually work, how come `totalSupply()` doesn't fail to keep track of the total number of tokens.

Comment: Which openzepplin extension u inheriting in contract for ERC721 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using ERC721Enumberable, the change is taken care from [ERC721Enumberable.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/4b16e887474eebb64e3f8266c68ef151a3f1b769/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol) `_allTokens` private variable, and not ERC777 as mentioned by my fellow user here. But yes  ***_safeMint()*** is the one that is responsible to change the ***totalSupply()*** internally.

-> in [ERC721.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol) there is `_safeMint` which invokes  `_mint`

->  `_mint` invokes `_beforeTokenTransfer`

-> now this `_beforeTokenTransfer` is virtual and is overriden by ERC721Enumberable contract

->  `_beforeTokenTransfer` invokes `_addTokenToAllTokensEnumeration`

-> `_addTokenToAllTokensEnumeration` invokes   `_allTokens.push(tokenId);` pushes the token in the array

-> `totalSupply()` reads from `_allTokens`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, now it is even clearer, have a good day !

Comment: Cheers fren. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

The total supply will be updated in the `_safeMint()` function.
In the openzeppelin implementation of the ERC777 that happens [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/4b16e887474eebb64e3f8266c68ef151a3f1b769/contracts/token/ERC777/ERC777.sol#L345).

Comment: Thank you ! now it is all clear